# Flutter on print showing Instance of Question

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from api which is working but problem is when i am printing the value its showing error if instance of question

Main.dart

```
  var questions = new List<Questions>();

  _getQuestions() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
      setState(() {

        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        print(list);
        print(list);
        questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
        print(questions);
      });
    });
  }
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getQuestions();
  }
```

Model

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Questions {
  String would;
  String rather;
  int wouldClick;
  int ratherClick;

  Questions(int wouldclick, int ratherclick, String would, String rather) {
    this.wouldClick = wouldClick;
    this.ratherClick = ratherClick;
    this.would = would;
    this.rather = rather;
  }

  Questions.fromJson(Map json)
      : wouldClick = json['wouldClick'],
        ratherClick = json['ratherClick'],
        would = json['would'],
        rather = json['rather'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'wouldClick': wouldClick, 'ratherClick': ratherClick, 'would': would, 'rather': rather};
  }

}
```

In console its showing like this

```
I/flutter ( 4808): [{rather: Tea, would: Coffe, wouldClick: 15, ratherClick: 12}, {rather: Oil, would: Soap, wouldClick: 50, ratherClick: 12}, {rather: Soap, would: Shaving Cream, wouldClick: 15, ratherClick: 12}]
I/flutter ( 4808): [Instance of 'Questions', Instance of 'Questions', Instance of 'Questions']
```

I need to print the list of question in JSON but it's showing this instance of questions error

Comment: override the `toString` method in your `Questions` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the `toString` method in your `Question` class

For example

```
class Questions {
  String would;
  String rather;
  int wouldClick;
  int ratherClick;

  Questions(int wouldclick, int ratherclick, String would, String rather) {
    this.wouldClick = wouldClick;
    this.ratherClick = ratherClick;
    this.would = would;
    this.rather = rather;
  }

  Questions.fromJson(Map json)
      : wouldClick = json['wouldClick'],
        ratherClick = json['ratherClick'],
        would = json['would'],
        rather = json['rather'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'wouldClick': wouldClick, 'ratherClick': ratherClick, 'would': would, 'rather': rather};
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Question(would: $would, rather: $rather, wouldClick: $wouldClick, ratherClick: $ratherClick)";
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks then how can i show this toString() in main.dart ?

Comment: You don't have to show it, it works directly. Accept?

Comment: Is it not possible to show in a json format ? Its seems like it's in a string format ?

Comment: You can customize the String to a Json format...but you can't return a JSON because of toString expects a String